# Can GeoFire handle uber-like applications well?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, geofire

I want to build an uber like app for android using GeoFire. For those who have more experience with it, is it worth the effort using Firebase's GeoFire to handle such an application? What are the main drawbacks of using such tool?

Comment: It is the best tool available to make a similar app like uber. The main drawback is there is not many documentations available for it.